# Parsing a log file with ANTLR

Tags: java, parsing, logging, antlr, antlr3

I need to parse a Weblogic log file with ANTLR. Here is the example:

```
Tue Aug 28 09:39:09 MSD 2012 [test] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] Alert - There is no user password credential mapper provider configured in your security realm. Oracle Service Bus service account management will be disabled. Configure a user password credential mapper provider if you need OSB service account support.

Sun Sep 02 23:13:00 MSD 2012 [test] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] Warning - Timer (Checkpoint) has been triggered with a tick (205 873) that is less than or equal to the last tick that was received (205 873). This could happen in a cluster due to clock synchronization with the timer authority. The current trigger will be ignored, and operation will be skipped.
Mon Sep 03 10:35:54 MSD 2012 [test] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '19' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] Info - 
 [OSB Tracing] Inbound request was received. 

 Service Ref = Some/URL
 URI = Another/URL
 Message ID = u-u-i-d
 Request metadata =
    <xml-fragment>
      <tran:headers xsi:type="http:HttpRequestHeaders" xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <http:Accept-Encoding>gzip, deflate,gzip, deflate</http:Accept-Encoding>
        <http:Connection>Keep-Alive</http:Connection>
        <http:Content-Length>666</http:Content-Length>
        <http:Content-Type>text/xml; charset=utf-8</http:Content-Type>
        <http:Host>some.host.name</http:Host>
        <http:SOAPAction>""</http:SOAPAction>
      </tran:headers>
      <tran:encoding xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">utf-8</tran:encoding>
      <http:client-host xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http">1.2.3.4</http:client-host>
      <http:client-address xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http">1.2.3.4</http:client-address>
      <http:http-method xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http">POST</http:http-method>
    </xml-fragment>
 Payload =  
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><XMLHere/></s:Envelope>
```

I am interested in this part of a log, everything else must be ignored (Date, Service Ref value and Envelope XML should be parsed):

```
Sun Sep 02 23:13:00 MSD 2012 [test] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] Warning - Timer (Checkpoint) has been triggered with a tick (205 873) that is less than or equal to the last tick that was received (205 873). This could happen in a cluster due to clock synchronization with the timer authority. The current trigger will be ignored, and operation will be skipped.
    Mon Sep 03 10:35:54 MSD 2012 [test] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '19' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] Info - 
     [OSB Tracing] Inbound request was received. 

     Service Ref = Some/URL
     URI = Another/URL
     Message ID = u-u-i-d
     Request metadata =
        <xml-fragment>
          <tran:headers xsi:type="http:HttpRequestHeaders" xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http" xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <http:Accept-Encoding>gzip, deflate,gzip, deflate</http:Accept-Encoding>
            <http:Connection>Keep-Alive</http:Connection>
            <http:Content-Length>666</http:Content-Length>
            <http:Content-Type>text/xml; charset=utf-8</http:Content-Type>
            <http:Host>some.host.name</http:Host>
            <http:SOAPAction>""</http:SOAPAction>
          </tran:headers>
          <tran:encoding xmlns:tran="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports">utf-8</tran:encoding>
          <http:client-host xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http">1.2.3.4</http:client-host>
          <http:client-address xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http">1.2.3.4</http:client-address>
          <http:http-method xmlns:http="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/http">POST</http:http-method>
        </xml-fragment>
     Payload =  
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><XMLHere/></s:Envelope>
```

Here is my lexer:

```
lexer grammar LogLexer;

options {filter=true;}

 /*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LEXER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
LOGDATE : DAY ' ' MONTH ' ' NUMDAY ' ' NUMTIME ' ' TIMEZONE ' ' NUMYEAR;

METAINFO : '[' .* ']' ' [[' .* ']' .* ']' .* '-' .* '[OSB Tracing] Inbound request was received.';

SERVICE_REF : 'Service Ref = ';

URI : (SYMBOL | '/')+;

ENVELOPE_TAG : '<' ENVELOPE_TAGNAME .* '>' .* '</' ENVELOPE_TAGNAME '>';

fragment
ENVELOPE_TAGNAME : SYMBOL+ ':Envelope';

fragment
NUMTIME : NUM NUM ':' NUM NUM ':' NUM NUM;

fragment
TIMEZONE : SYMBOL SYMBOL SYMBOL;

fragment
DAY : 'Sun' | 'Mon' | 'Tue' | 'Wed' | 'Fri' | 'Sat';

fragment
MONTH :  'Sep' | 'Oct' | 'Nov' | 'Dec' | 'Feb' | 'Mar' | 'May' | 'Apr' | 'Jun' | 'Jul' | 'Aug';

fragment
NUMYEAR : NUM NUM NUM NUM;

fragment
NUMDAY : NUM NUM;

fragment
NUM : '0'..'9';

fragment
SYMBOL : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
```

And here is the parser (not finished yet):

```
grammar LogParser;

options {
tokenVocab = OSBLogLexer;
}

@header {
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
}

parse 
    returns [List<List<String>> entries] 
    @init {
        $entries = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    }
    : requestLogEntry+
    {
        $entries.add($requestLogEntry.logEntry);
    };

requestLogEntry 
    returns [List<String> logEntry]
    @init {
        $logEntry = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    : LOGDATE METAINFO .* serviceRef .* ENVELOPE_TAG
    {
        $logEntry.add($LOGDATE.getText());
        $logEntry.add($serviceRef.serviceURI);
        $logEntry.add($ENVELOPE_TAG.getText());
    };

serviceRef 
    returns [String serviceURI] 
    : SERVICE_REF URI 
    {
        $serviceURI = $URI.getText();
    };
```

The problem is that it parses log incorrectly. My code does not ignore unwanted records, so I get invalid DATE value in resulting list: Tue Aug 28 09:39:09 MSD 2012 (the first one in the example) instead of Mon Sep 03 10:35:54 MSD 2012 (the correct one). Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

**UPDATE**

I have updated my code, but I get generation errors. Can't see what is wrong.

Updated lexer:

```
lexer grammar LogLexer;

options {
    filter=true;
}

TRASH : LOGDATE ' ' METAINFO (' ' | '\n')* { skip(); };

LOGDATE : DAY ' ' MONTH ' ' NUMDAY ' ' NUMTIME ' ' TIMEZONE ' ' NUMYEAR;

METAINFO : ('[' | ']' | SYMBOL | NUM | ' ' | SPECIAL)+;

OSB_METAINFO : (' ' | '\n')* '[OSB Tracing] Inbound request was received.';

SERVICE_REF : 'Service Ref = ';

URI : (SYMBOL | '/')+;

ENVELOPE_TAG : '<' ENVELOPE_TAGNAME .* '>' .* '</' ENVELOPE_TAGNAME '>';

fragment
OSB_TRACING : '[OSB Tracing] Inbound request was received.';

fragment
ENVELOPE_TAGNAME : SYMBOL+ ':Envelope';

fragment
NUMTIME : NUM NUM ':' NUM NUM ':' NUM NUM;

fragment
TIMEZONE : SYMBOL SYMBOL SYMBOL;

fragment
DAY : 'Sun' | 'Mon' | 'Tue' | 'Wed' | 'Fri' | 'Sat';

fragment
MONTH :  'Sep' | 'Oct' | 'Nov' | 'Dec' | 'Feb' | 'Mar' | 'May' | 'Apr' | 'Jun' | 'Jul' | 'Aug';

fragment
NUMYEAR : NUM NUM NUM NUM;

fragment
NUMDAY : NUM NUM;

fragment
NUM : '0'..'9';

fragment
SYMBOL : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');

fragment
SPECIAL : ( ~'\n' | '\'' | '.' | '(' | ')' | '-');
```

Updated parser:

```
parser grammar LogParser;

options {
    tokenVocab = LogLexer;
}

@header {
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
}

parse returns [List<List<String>> entries] 
    @init {
        $entries = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    }
    : requestLogEntry+
    {
        $entries.add($requestLogEntry.logEntry);
    };

requestLogEntry 
    returns [List<String> logEntry]
    @init {
        $logEntry = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    :  LOGDATE ' ' METAINFO OSB_METAINFO .* serviceRef .* ENVELOPE_TAG
    {
        $logEntry.add($LOGDATE.getText());
        $logEntry.add($serviceRef.serviceURI);
        $logEntry.add($ENVELOPE_TAG.getText());
    };

serviceRef 
    returns [String serviceURI] 
    : SERVICE_REF URI 
    {
        $serviceURI = $URI.getText();
    };
```

Lexer generation errors:

```
[14:18:12] error(204): LogLexer.g:56:21: duplicate token type '\'' when collapsing subrule into set
[14:18:12] error(204): LogLexer.g:56:28: duplicate token type '.' when collapsing subrule into set
[14:18:12] error(204): LogLexer.g:56:34: duplicate token type '(' when collapsing subrule into set
[14:18:12] error(204): LogLexer.g:56:40: duplicate token type ')' when collapsing subrule into set
[14:18:12] error(204): LogLexer.g:56:46: duplicate token type '-' when collapsing subrule into set
[14:18:12] error(204): LogLexer.g:56:21: duplicate token type '\'' when collapsing subrule into set
[14:18:12] error(204): LogLexer.g:56:28: duplicate token type '.' when collapsing subrule into set
[14:18:12] error(204): LogLexer.g:56:34: duplicate token type '(' when collapsing subrule into set
[14:18:12] error(204): LogLexer.g:56:40: duplicate token type ')' when collapsing subrule into set
[14:18:12] error(204): LogLexer.g:56:46: duplicate token type '-' when collapsing subrule into set
```

Those errors seem to happen randomly and randomly dissappear (file rename). Also ANTLR generates another lexer from my parser file (this also happens randomly). I am using last avaliable ANTLR3 and ANTLRWorks on Windows 7 (x64).

Comment: Is it correct that you are looking for dates plus the service request, and want to discard the bare dates without a service request and following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I'm tracking what is a valid versus an invalid service request, but I'll plow ahead anyway.

Your parser is looking for

```
LOGDATE METAINFO .* serviceRef .* ENVELOPE_TAG
```

Before it can start parsing, the lexer is looking for that LOGDATE + METAINFO + some stuff + serviceRef.

The lexer doesn't know that you want it to discard the first two LOGDATEs that don't have a serviceRef and only consider the third entry that has the serviceRef. Therefore, it will parse the first line as the beginning of a full-fledged entry.

Without giving you the answer and robbing you of the joy that comes from a deep understanding antlr, I would suggest that you have your lexer "understand" more of how both a proper entry is built. The lexer should also understand how an incorrect entry is built.

In other words, how would you rewrite the lexer so that it handles some lexemes and says that the first two lines are "just a date" and the third is the real deal?

Answer (score 3):

> *Those errors seem to happen randomly and randomly dissappear (file rename).*

No, they don't happen randomly. The errors originate from the rule:

```
fragment
SPECIAL : ( ~'\n' | '\'' | '.' | '(' | ')' | '-');
```

The set `~'\n'` already matches `'\'' | '.' | '(' | ')' | '-'`. You probably meant:

```
fragment
SPECIAL : ~('\n' | '\'' | '.' | '(' | ')' | '-');
```

> *Also ANTLR generates another lexer from my parser file (this also happens randomly). I am using last avaliable ANTLR3 and ANTLRWorks on Windows 7 (x64).*

That only happens if you don't specify a type of grammar. For example: `grammar T` (a so called combined grammar) generates both a lexer and parser, where `parser grammar T` and `lexer grammar T` only generate a parser and lexer respectively. I saw you posted a combined grammar at first. The "extra" lexer class might be a remnant from when you had a combined grammar.

Also, be sure ***not*** to use any literal tokens in your parser grammar! (remove the `' '` from the `requestLogEntry` rule).

Comment: use your explanation to solve my problem. thanks.
my detail is here: http://www.crifan.com/antlr_cannot_generate_the_grammar_because_duplicate_token_type_when_collapsing_subrule_into_set/

Answer (score 0):

kernel_mode!

I'm not sure, that the way you chose for parsing log file is most suitable.

It seems to me, that Antlr is intended for describing context-free grammars.
In your case we have a deal with a simplest regular grammar.

According to my experience I dare make a point, that for parsing log-files in a line-by-line mode, a *reader* is a more easy and optimal method. Such algorithm will look like that:

1. read a line. Go to p. 2.1.
   2.1 if the line starts with an expression which matches the regular expression (for parsing "Mon Sep 03 10:35:54 MSD 2012") - parse it and save the result for further parsing. Go to p. 1.
   2.2 if the line doesn't match to the above mentioned regexp, then go to p. 3.
2. read lines until a line matches with the reg.exp from p.2.1. Go to p. 4.
3. try to cut an XML from a read block (using simple string functions). Go to p. 5.
4. Contains XML? => Parse XML and use the previously saved parsed result for log-date. 
   Then go to p.1.

Comment: Using `filter=true` in a lexer grammar, you don't need to describe the entire language/input you're parsing. In short: ANTLR *can* be used for this task (a line-by-line solution could also be used as you propose, of course, but ANTLR would be appropriate here as well, IMO).

Comment: Bart, I just mean, that Antlr is powerful tool for parsing more complex texts. In this question's issue writing own simple line-by-line solution is more easy and lightweight way, according to standard log file structure.

Comment: I know, I understand that. I however say that although ANTLR can be used for way more complex tasks, it can also be used in this context.